# ASP.NET Print Function: to print asp.net controls with its style

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an intranet web application. And I want to develop simple print function that I can use it to print a specific part from the web page and I can use it to print GridView or ListView with its style. I am searching about it in the web and most of what I found is javascript function that print the GridView, for example, with its style.

For instance, I used this [Print Function](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=92) that is based in C# class and it works but it prints the controls like GridView without its style that I have it in the webpage. So is there any simple function for printing?

Comment: assuming your data comes from a database, Reporting Services provides all facilities to print/export lists/grids of data, i'd strongly suggest this approach so you don't sort of "reinvent the wheel" in your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your not render css during printing the page

according your link reference just add your stylesheet url in `PrintWebControl` function code

i.e

```
string strHTML = stringWrite.ToString();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<link href='/Styles/Site.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTML);
```

Hops its helps

Comment: Thanks for your help, but still nothing works with formatting the page. It is still displaying without formattting

Comment: strange..its work in my page.can u render panel or gridview?.Or r u check console that your stylesheet loaded or not?

Comment: it works well now. It is my fault. Thanks dude. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to add a customize header or footer. Because I am using a special stylesheet for printing and even with putting header and footer there, it does not work.