# how to print the gridview of page in require format

Tags: asp.net, gridview, printing, printing-web-page

I have a gridview from database and the issue is i want to print the whole page when the user click the print button each row of gridview print in given format as 3 row on 1 A4 size page.

**gridview**
[image]

**Printing format**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to using javascript so you can try this

```
function printItn() {
                  //In my case i have append gridview in Panel that y..you can put your contentID which is you want to print.

                    var printContent = document.getElementById('<%= pnlForm.ClientID %>');
                    var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
                    var uniqueName = new Date();
                    var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();

        //  you should add all css refrence for your Gridview. something like.

                    var WinPrint= window.open(windowUrl,windowName,'left=300,top=300,right=500,bottom=500,width=1000,height=500');WinPrint.document.write('<'+'html'+'><head><link href="cssreference" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="gridviewcssrefrence" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head><'+'body style="background:none !important"'+'>');
                    WinPrint.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
                    WinPrint.document.write('<'+'/body'+'><'+'/html'+'>');
                    WinPrint.document.close();
                    WinPrint.focus();
                    WinPrint.print();
                    WinPrint.close();
                    }
```

Hops its helps

Comment: you should try this link..http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=92 or also see this [question]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561744/asp-net-print-function-to-print-asp-net-controls-with-its-style/9562504#9562504 may be help u!!!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use some reporting framework such as SSRS/Report-Viewer, Crystal Reports for generating such output.

For example, you can create the report definition in RDLC file having a group on some ranking function (to ensure three rows) and display it using ReportViewer control - have a look at this site for more information about reportviewer: http://gotreportviewer.com/